# Maximum Possible File Name Length in Windows Kernel

Tags: winapi, path, kernel, filenames, name-length

I was wondering, what is the **longest** possible name length allowed by the Windows kernel?

E.g.: I know the kernel uses `UNICODE_STRING` structures to hold all object paths, and since the byte length of a wide-character string is stored inside a `USHORT`, that allows for a maximum path length of 2^15 - 1 characters. Is there a similar, *hard* restriction on a file name (rather than path)? (I don't care if NTFS or FAT32 imposes a particular restriction; I'm looking for the longest possible theoretically allowed name in the kernel, assuming no additional file system or shell restrictions.)

(Edit: For those wondering why this even matters, consider that normally, traversing a directory is achieved by `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` calls, one call per file. Given the function named `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, which is the underlying system call and which returns *multiple* file names per call, it's actually possible to take advantage of this maximum-length restriction on the path to make an extremely-fast directory traverser that uses solely the stack as a buffer. Now I'm trying to extend that concept, and I need to know the maximum size of a file name.)

Comment: When you say USHORT and then 2^31, what do you mean? If it is unsigned then it would be 2^32, but a ushort only stores up to 2^16 (It's 16bits long) Have I misunderstood your meaning somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo; I meant 2^15 - 1. I changed it, thanks.

Comment: And I forgot to take into account that each character needs 2 bytes of memory, halving the amount space you get... Anyway, I'm guessing that such a limit in the kernel would be poorly documented and vary from XP to Vista/Win7. Hope someone can help you, +1

Comment: Is your method measurably faster enough to make any meaningful difference?  If there is some internal limit, what would stop Microsoft from changing it in the future?  As far as I know path components are limited only by the underlying file-system; I doubt it's ever going to go above 255 in the foreseeable future (mainly for backward compatibility purposes).

Comment: Yes, it iterates through my entire C: drive (which has Windows 7, with a total of about 400,000 files) in less than four seconds, if the entire data to be read is cached in system memory. As soon as I switch to using malloc() instead of stack-based memory, the time taken at least doubles -- sometimes more. And I've noticed that it's probably one or two orders of magnitude faster than Explorer when it searches for files. If you're interested, I can post the code somewhere, although it's written in D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc422524.aspx) myself that **guarantees** that file names can't be longer than 255 characters:

> - A pathname MUST be no more than 32,760 characters in length.
>   ...
> - Each pathname component MUST be no more than 255 characters in length.

Which makes me wonder:

#### Why does Windows [use `ULONG`s for file *name* lengths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540248.aspx), when it [uses `USHORT`s for *path* lengths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749(v=vs.85).aspx)?!

If anyone knows why this is, please post/comment! I'm rather curious. :)

Comment: The ULONGs are probably used to maintain alignment with the other fields in the directory information header records. The USHORT limit of UNICODE_STRING is the real limit. Using a USHORT in the info header would either require a padding value or put the rest of the structure out of alignment. Note that each header record needs to be aligned by 8 byes.

Answer (score 5):

The maximum length of a path is 32,767 characters whereby each path component (directory or file) can have a maximum length of 255 characters (to be more exact, the value returned in the lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation function).

This is [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath).

Comment: +1, Thank you for the link, it's useful. But I'm looking for a compile-time, absolute maximum, and the page says 255 is "commonly" the maximum. So my question is, there any absolute upper barrier aside from 32K?

Comment: (Oops sorry, forgot to give the +1; fixed.) :)

Comment: I think I'll just accept this since I don't think there's a better answer. Thanks. :)