# Is this a good use for "mutable" in C++?

Tags: visual-c++, static-libraries

I have a class that wraps a file handle:

```
class FileHandle
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    TCHAR name[256];
public:
    LPCTSTR getName() const { /*(query system for name)*/ return this->name; }
};
```

I have come up with a design choice:

Since I will be querying the file name often, in order to minimize heap allocations which would happen if I returned `std::wstring` (I have repeatedly seen that this is a bottleneck in my programs), I have instead decided to keep a `name` field *inside* the object itself, and just return a pointer to it as shown.

Of course, the name of the file can change over time, so I can't avoid querying it every time. I can only avoid the *reallocation*.

Of course, the section saying `(query system for name)` would **not** work as shown because `name` isn't `mutable`.

On the one hand, the caller doesn't *expect* the file name to change. But on the other hand, that's **not** what `const` means, anyway. The name can certainly change, it's just that the caller can't modify it. So it doesn't look like it should be a problem, but I'm not too sure.

Under what circumstances would it be a good idea for me to use `mutable` here? Why?

<sub>**Note 1: Windows *guarantees* that file names are at most 256 characters long**, so there's no buffer overflow issue to consider here.</sub>

<sub>**Note 2: The class is only designed for *single-threaded* use.** I'm not worried about *concurrent* modifications, only modifications *in between* statements.</sub>

---

#### Why `const` doesn't imply immutability:

This should be self-explanatory:

```
FileHandle file = ...;
const FileHandle &fileConst(file);
LPCTSTR name1 = fileConst.getName();
file.setName(_T("new name"));
LPCTSTR name2 = fileConst.getName();
```

Now `name1` and `name2` aren't equal. So not *only* can the file name change quite easily, but *`name1` itself* can also change -- even though they're both `const`. There's no rule saying that `const` members can't change, just that they can't be changed *through the `const` reference*.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? I see nothing wrong with the code...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The `(query system for name)` wouldn't work, because it would modify the buffer.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444695

Comment: @PeterRader: Thanks for the link but it doesn't seem to quite address my question.

Comment: `Windows guarantees that file names are at most 256 characters long`, thats only on the ANSI version of the functions.

Comment: @K-ballo: [No, it's for **all** file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624057/maximum-possible-file-name-length-in-windows-kernel/7192779#7192779).

Comment: sorry, i ment you better use volatile as @K-ballo wrote below.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Granted, I tend to confuse file name with file path.

Answer (score 2):

The missing method here, as I see it, is `setName`. There's no problem with your code as it is, because there's no way to change `name`, and changing it via `getName` is awkward. So, assuming you'd have some

```
void setName(LPCTSTR newName) { _tcscpy(name, newName); /*or so*/ }
```

Question now is how you'd expect it to be used. It makes sense that whoever is supposed to be changing the name, has access to a non-const `FileHandle`. In such case, there's no problem using this trivial `setName`. If, however, the file name should be changed on a `const FileHandle`, you have two problems: first, it's awkward... and second, you won't be able to call the `setName` above. To be able to call it, you'd have to change it to

```
void setName(LPCTSTR newName) const { _tcscpy(name, newName); /*or so*/ }
```

which doesn't really makes sense either, but let's pretend it does. Now, this won't work, because `FileHandle` being const would effectively make `name` const as well. And this finally brings us to `mutable`: changing `name`'s declaration to:

```
mutable TCHAR name[256 + 1 /*for NULL terminator*/];
```

will indeed allow you to use `setName` to change the name of a `const FileHandle`. To me, this looks like a sign of a bad design, where you're actually hacking your own code. For that matter, you can just `const_cast` the `FileHandle`, and change it without using `mutable`. But I really don't know the specifics of your case, so maybe it does make sense...

---

Update, given the information that `getName` actually checks the name of the file, and updates `name` if needed before returning it: in that case, making `name` mutable would indeed be the way to go, because otherwise it can't be changed from within a const method. It is generally not advised for a getter to change the value of the member whose value it's getting, but if your case dictates that, then making `name` a `mutable` would make sense.

Comment: Well, the file name is queried from the *system* each time, and it could change for the duration of the program (e.g. because the user changed it by hand, without my knowledge). That's why I update the value inside `getName` -- there's no need for `setName` to actually change the value.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I wasn't aware of that, updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, the name of the file can change over time

Are you sure about that? Can a file name be changed while there is an open handle to it? If that's the case, then this is not a good use of `mutable`. `mutable` is there to achieve **logical constness** when **bitwise constness** cannot be achieved, like is the case with cached data. However, callers of your `getName()` function would be surprissed if two consecutive `const` calls would return different values.

**Update:**

If the property is expected to change from outside the program declaration, then you should make that statement by declaring the function `const volatile`, and then the use of `mutable` **may** be justified. However note there is another problem with this approach, in that a caller of the function keeps the pointer to the file name around and a subsequent call to the function will change its contents. That means that the result of this function should be considered `volatile` as well.

**Update 2:**

There is no rule in the standard that dictates the uses of `const`, no one will stop you from flagging all your functions `const` and your members `volatile`. However, `const` is usually used to indicate that the logical constness of the object won't change by invoking a member function; and `volatile` is usually used to indicate that the value may be changed from outside the application. The question is about **good use** of `mutable` -which I consider subjective-, and `mutable` is not an outsider to this particular use case specially if the function has a `volatile` modifier as well. However, `const volatile` modifiers are rare, `const` functions returning different values after subsequent calls are rare, and values being changed outside your control are rare. Considering not only the function signature but the ammount of warnings that the documentation should include, I think that the surprise factor is high enough for this to be considered a bad use case at least in my book.

Comment: They might be surprised, but should they be? `const` does **not** imply that the data is *immutable*, but that it can't be changed *through* the `const` reference.

Comment: @Mehrdad: They will, at least **I** will. If the data can be changed from outside the application then I would expect to see `volatile`.

Comment: See my example in my post. It's **very** easy for something `const` to change, it requires nothing fancy with `mutable` or whatever -- and it's certainly 100% consistent with the rules (and expectations) of `const`, which have nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: @Mehrdad: At first, I was going to disagree with you. But after thinking about it some more, I actually agree. If we think about this as some sort of simple Model-View situation, then it makes sense. Just because the view is `const`, doesn't mean that the underlying data in the model will never change. It just means that the user can't use the view to change the model.

Comment: @K-ballo: Hmmm... I don't *quite* understand, though. Is this really a volatility issue, or an aliasing issue? I don't see why the compiler should need to re-evaluate the expression, because it's certainly not changing "beyond the scope" of the compiler.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: Yup, exactly. :) This was [the exact reason why D introduced `immutable`](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/const3.html), btw.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is acceptable, but not ideal.  I think logically you have a name that is independent the file handle.  You are not asking for the name of the file handle, you are asking for the name of the file that the file handle is referring to.  Getting that name doesn't change the file handle, so the logical constness is preserved.  What is not ideal is that the results could change in unexpected ways:

```
LPCTSTR old_name = filehandle.getname();
changeFileName(filehandle);
LPCTSTR new_name = filehandle.getname();
// but old_name and new name still match!
```

But that is really independent of whether or not the member should be made mutable.

Comment: It's not quite independent if `getname` is `const`, because otherwise `getname` couldn't update the internal buffer... right?

Comment: The getname method could be implemented in other ways that had the same behavior without using mutable.  For example, it could return a pointer to a static variable.